# Laptop turns off suddenly, then wont turn on again

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, power

This laptop started to present this problem in which it turns on briefly for about one minute, then it suddenly turns off and after that wont turn on again. If I wait about one month or so and try again it will turn on but suddenly off and the same process repeats.

Things I tried already without success:

- Disconnect the battery and power cord an hold down the power button for a minute and try again (It still wont turn on, not even the power light)
- Trying with just the battery, or just with the power cord. Also a different power cord.
- Disconnecting all the things from the motherboard and trying to turn it on (no response also)
- Replacing the RAM (No response also)
- Cleaning the motherboard with isopropyl alcohol
- Tried not booting windows and remaining on the BIOS to see if it would turn off regardless of the operating system (It did turn off suddenly regardless)

This laptop model is a Dell inspiron 14R 5420, it is about 10 years old now

Answer (score 5):

It would appear the motherboard has a fault. If the CPU were overheating, it would recover (cool down) within a few minutes and repeat.

You may wish to contact Dell Support about servicing it.

However, at 10 years of age, it has done its tour of duty and it is now time to replace it. This seems to me to be the best course of action here.

You can likely put the disk drive in a carrier and recover data you need.

Answer (score -4):

I agree with everything the guy above said except contacting dell support.
You'd be spending a lot of time and possibly money that is not worthwhile. I encountered a problem like this once working at a laptop repair place, so the fact that it won't turn back on wouldn't indicate overheating, which can be another cause if it starts to overheat, I seem to remember some mobos have a built in feature that instead of throttling, like one generation, just turns the thing off completely.